# Fastest way to check which interval index a value is

Tags: python, numpy

I have a vector like this:

```
intervals = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11] #always regular
```

I want to check which interval index a value is. For example: the index of the interval where `8.5` is, is `3`.

```
#Interval : index
6  -> 7   : 1
7  -> 8   : 2
8  -> 9   : 3
9  -> 10  : 4
10 -> 11  : 5
```

So I made this code:

```
from numpy import *
N = 8000
data = random.random(N)
step_number = 50
max_value = max(data)
min_value = min(data)
step_length = (max_value - min_value)/step_number
intervals = arange(min_value + step_length, max_value + step_length, step_length )
for x in data:
    for index in range(len(intervals)):
        if x < intervals[index]:
            print("That's the index", index)
            break
```

This code is working, but It's tooo slow, I think I'm wasting time in these loops. Is there a way to check this faster? Maybe using some numpy special function that check this for me...

Comment: If the intervals are evenly spaced as in your example, you should be able to calculate the index, as opposed to searching for it.

Comment: You can use a binary search if the interval is sorted -- Python even has the `bisect` module builtin...

Comment: Thinking about your answers :D

Comment: If the intervals are regular (as above) you can just compute the position directly which would be `O(1)` time. If the intervals are irregular, but sorted, you can use binary search to find the solution in `O(log n)` time. If the intervals are irregular and unsorted you can find the solution in two passes which is `O(n)` time

Comment: Nesting your loops as above gives you quadratic time which isn't optimal at all.

Comment: Calculate would be faster than the binary search? In my case, the intervals are always regular

Comment: Yes, calculating directly is constant time.

Comment: @Mr.Felix -- If the intervals are regular, then calculation will be faster for any circumstance where it matters.

Comment: Are the intervals always one unit?

Comment: No, they can have any length. And thinking about the calculation here...

Comment: So the separate isn't always 1, but it's always the same length for a given interval list?

Comment: Yeah, I always create the interval list using `arange()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on how you want to handle the endpoints, there is `bisect.bisect_left` and `bisect.bisect_right`:

```
>>> import bisect
>>> intervals = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
>>> for n in (6, 6.1, 6.2, 6.5, 6.8, 7):
...   print bisect.bisect_left(intervals, n)
... 
0
1
1
1
1
1
>>> for n in (6, 6.1, 6.2, 6.5, 6.8, 7):
...   print bisect.bisect_right(intervals, n)
... 
1
1
1
1
1
2
```

Numpy implements the same thing using the [`searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) method.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.searchsorted(intervals, (6, 6.1, 6.2, 6.5, 6.8, 7), side='left')
array([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
>>> np.searchsorted(intervals, (6, 6.1, 6.2, 6.5, 6.8, 7), side='right')
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2])
```

And, of course, if your intervals are equally spaced, you can do:

```
>>> for n in (6, 6.1, 6.2, 6.5, 6.8, 7):
...     iwidth = intervals[1] - intervals[0]
...     print np.ceil((n - intervals[0]) / iwidth)
... 
0.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
```

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned, if you have irregular intervals, use a bisecting search (e.g. [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) and/or [`np.digitize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html)).

However, in your specific case where you've stated you'll always have regular intervals, you can also do something similar to:

```
import numpy as np

intervals = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
vals = np.array([8.5, 6.2, 9.8])

dx = intervals[1] - intervals[0]
x0 = intervals[0]

i = np.ceil((vals - x0) / dx).astype(int)
```

Or, building on your example code:

```
import numpy as np

N = 8000
num_intervals = 50

data = np.random.random(N)
intervals = np.linspace(data.min(), data.max(), num_intervals)

x0 = intervals[0]
dx = intervals[1] - intervals[0]
i = np.ceil((data - x0) / dx).astype(int)
```

This will be much faster than a binary search for large arrays.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your list is sorted, you can use the [bisect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) library to get the insertion index.

```
index = bisect.bisect_left(intervals, 8.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `numpy.digitize`:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html#numpy-digitize

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> intervals = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
>>> data = [3.5, 6.3, 9.4, 11.5, 8.5]

>>> np.digitize(data, bins=interval)
array([0, 1, 4, 6, 3])
```

`0` is underflow, `len(intervals)` is overflow

Answer (score 0):

Just using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

intervals = np.array([6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11])
val = (intervals > 8.5)
print val.argmax()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for a function:

```
def f_idx(f_list, number):
    for idx,item in enumerate(f_list):
        if item>number:
            return idx
    return len(f_list)
```

In one liner:

```
result = [idx for idx,value in enumerate(intervals) if value>number][0] if intervals[-1]>number else len(intervals)
```