# Python: fastest way to check in which interval number is in

Tags: python, numpy, if-statement, pytorch

Suppose I have split the interval `[0, 1]` into a series of smaller intervals `[0, 0.2), [0.2, 0.4), [0.4, 0.9), [0.9, 1.0]`. Now I sample a value `r` in `[0, 1]`. What is the fastest way I can check in which interval this belongs to using Python / Numpy / Pytorch?

The obvious way is this:

```
r = np.random.rand()
if 0 <= r < 0.2:
    pass # do something
elif 0.2 <= r < 0.4:
    pass # do something else
elif 0.4 <= r < 0.9:
    pass # do yet something else again
elif 0.9 <= r <= 1.0:
    pass # do some other thing
```

Comment: For one number, that's about as fast as you can :-). Otherwise, look at  `np.searchsorted`.

Comment: Don't you think a binary search would be faster on a large number of bins @QuangHoang? [numpy.digitize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) is available for that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34798343/fastest-way-to-check-which-interval-index-a-value-is

Comment: @MarkMeyer That's true. What was I thinking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way to check which interval index a value is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34798343/fastest-way-to-check-which-interval-index-a-value-is)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to first transform your list of intervals into a list of boundaries, so instead of many intervals `[0, 0.2), [0.2, 0.4), [0.4, 0.9), [0.9, 1.0]`, you just define:

```
boundaries = [0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.9, 1.0]  # values must be sorted!!
```

Then you can perform a binary search over all of them, to see in which segment a `value` belongs:

```
index = bisect.bisect_right(boundaries, value)
```

`index` will be the index of the upper bound, so to get the range, you'd to:

```
range_low = boundaries[index - 1] if index > 0 else None
range_high = boundaries[index] if index < len(boundaries) else None
```

This will also take care of handling values which are not in any of the intervals. The binary search will be done in `log(N)` compares, which is the theoretical best thing you can do for arbitrary intervals.

Comment: if value is exactly, for example, `0.4`, this will not work. It gives the interval to the left of the proper one. Perhaps this is an easy fix though, `bisect` instead of `bisect_left` ?

Comment: @L.Grozinger True, I changed it to `bisect_right` now (which is the same as `bisect`, but more explicit).

Answer (score 1):

The `bisect` module contains a function `bisect` which uses a bisection algorithm to index into a sorted list. This should be roughly `O(log n)`.

```
from bisect import bisect
```

You can keep your rightmost values of your intervals in a list, and a list of functions which do something appropriate in the same order. E.g.

```
def a():
    print("Do something")


intervals = [0.2, 0.4, 0.9, 1]

stufftodo = [a, a, a, a]
```

You can, of course, have different functions for each interval. You can then use the index returned by bisect to index into `stufftodo`, extract the appropriate function, and call it.

```
r = np.random.rand()
stufftodo[bisect(intervals, r)]()
```